# How to use Puppeteer's page.click inside a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to make [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) click on some tabs based on the number of items in an array called `tabs`:

```
;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  })   

  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(`https://www.example.com`)

  const tabs = ['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3']

  tabs.forEach((tab, index) => {
    await page.click(`.postab-container li:nth-of-type(${ index + 1 }) a`)
  })
})()
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> await page.click(`.postab-container li:nth-of-type(${ index + 1 }) a`)
>       ^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> ```

It seems like the `forEach` statement is messing up `page`.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

The function inside of the forEach is not an `async` function so you cannot use `await`, but even if you changed it to an `async` function you would not get the result you anticipate (forEach will generate all the requests at once, and not `await` each `async function`). Use a for loop instead.

```
  for(let index =0;index<tabs.length;++index){
    let tab = tabs[index];
    await page.click(`.postab-container li:nth-of-type(${ index + 1 }) a`)
  }
```